# sorting with Order By in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql as database and i have a table like the one below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logins` (  
    `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `userid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
    `date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
    `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
    KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=346 ;
```

I want to sort mysql results with order by.The problem is when i use this sql it takes only the first recod of date. Which is an older date. I want the newest date. last login date of user.

```
SELECT * FROM `logins` WHERE `status`='valid' GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have GROUP BY but no AGGREGATE in your SELECT.

Comment: As above, in the absence of any aggregating functions, your use of GROUP BY is inappropriate. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so (and you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Translation: Remove "GROUP BY userid"

Comment: Further point, which date it takes off is not defined. It might choose to only give you the first date or it might choose the last. There is no guarantee that all the other fields will below to the same row as the one chosen for the date either (although they probably are).

Comment: It looks like you want `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1` and remove the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you use a sub query to get the latest record for each user id and then join that to the logins table to get the rest of the details

```
SELECT logins.*
FROM logins
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userid, MAX(`date`) AS max_date
    FROM `logins`
    WHERE `status` = 'valid' 
    GROUP BY `userid` 
) sub0
ON logins.userid = sub0.userid
AND logins.`date` = sub0.max_date
WHERE `status` = 'valid'
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Assuming id and userId doesn't evolve from one login to another, asking the MAX date should give you the expected result.

```
SELECT id, userId, MAX(`date`) AS lastDate, 'valid'
FROM `logins`
WHERE `status`='valid'
GROUP BY `userid`
ORDER BY `lastDate` DESC
```

Please note that you would need a JOIN if there were data that change between logins in the table.